# How to pass value to the filter in DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatable, filtering, datatables

I need to make custom filter, and I use special function in datatable, and it filter, but when I look the request that i made to filter, the value that is send to filter is always empty.

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var table = jQuery('#example2').DataTable();
        jQuery("#segment").on("change", function(e) {
            var segment = jQuery('#segment').select2('data').text;
            table.draw();
    } );
```

and I use this to push the value, and I dont get anything from here, even in console.log

```
//filter push
    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {

            //main filter
            var segment = jQuery('#segment').select2('data').text;
            var marke   = jQuery('#model').select2('data').text;

            console.log(segment);
            if( aData[1]== segment ||
                aData[3]== marke )
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
    );
```

Comment: Try `var segment = jQuery('#segment').select2('data').text()`;

Comment: The string that I get is not a function, and I dont think its a problem. The problem is that I dont get access to "jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push" because when I tried to console.log dummy data, it doesnt show.

Comment: Ok - but without more code we cannot be certain you are (a) defining the extention, (b) calling it correctly?

Comment: I am new to datatabel, and I tough by writing" jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push"  i am defining the extention. How do you define? the rest of code is calling ajax request and handaling with ajax   I was using this example http://www.datatables.net/development/filtering

Comment: ok - you've got 2 things going on here, Datatables which looks to be ok and then `select2` Having just looked it up I think the syntax you want is `$("#segment").select2("val")` etc.

Comment: I have change it, considering select2, you can use both ways, but how do I define which value will send to the filter

Answer (score 0):

You need only to return `true` or `false` to make the filter work.  You can get the values of the `segment` and `marke` as you currently are doing it.  Just test that they actually are retrieving the values as you do by either `console.log(segment, marke)` or `alert(segment, marke)` Everything should work as long as you are getting the correct values.  Perhaps showing your HTML.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var table = jQuery('#example2').DataTable();
        jQuery("#segment").on("change", function(e) {
            // You do not need this as filter is run on a new table.draw();
            // var segment = jQuery('#segment').select2('data').text;
            table.draw();
    } );

//filter push
    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {

            //main filter
            var segment = jQuery('#segment').select2('val');
            var marke   = jQuery('#model').select2('val');
            //Check whether you are getting an output from the log method below in your console
            console.log(segment, marke);
            if( aData[1]== segment ||
                aData[3]== marke )
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
    );
```